# Tangent line to a concave down function stays above the function

Tags: calculus

Suppose we know that $f'(x) \gt 0$ and and $f''(x)\lt0$ for all real number $x$. How to show that $f(x_1) + f'(x_1)(x-x_1) \ge f(x)$ for all real $x,x_1$?

---

As an example if we consider a `concave down` function like $f(x) = \ln x$, any tangent to it at any point stays above the function. From the graph it makes sense intuitively, and if we want to prove this, we may try showing :
$$ \ln(x_1)+ \frac{1}{x_1}(x-x_1) \ge \ln x$$
for all $x\gt 0,x_1\gt 0$.
But if possible I'd like to work the general case... Any help?

Comment: Did you mean to use an inequality in $f(x_1) + f'(x)(x-x_1) \gt f(x)$ as, otherwise, choosing $x = x_1$ gives $f(x_1) \gt f(x_1)$?

Comment: Ah right, ty :) I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality is true for $x = x_1$. For any $x$, choose any $x_1 \lt x$. Then by the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there's a $c \in (x_1,x)$ such that

$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(x_1)}{x - x_1} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Since $f''(y) \lt 0$ for all real $y$, this means $f'(x_1) \gt f'(c)$. Substituting this into \eqref{eq1} and cross-multiplying by $x - x_1$ gives

$$f'(x_1)(x - x_1) \gt f(x) - f(x_1) \implies f(x_1) + f'(x_1)(x - x_1) \gt f(x) \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

You can use a similar argument for the case where $x_1 \gt x$.

Comment: For $x_1\gt x$, there's a $c\in (x,x_1)$ s.t : $$f'(c)=\dfrac{f(x_1)-f(x)}{x_1-x}$$
Since $f''(x)\lt 0$, this means $f'(x_1)\lt f'(c)$.
$$f'(x_1)\lt f'(c)=\dfrac{f(x_1)-f(x)}{x_1-x} \implies f(x)\lt f(x_1)+f'(x_1)(x-x_1)$$

Comment: You've used MVT is such cool way. Thank you so much I get this :)

Comment: @rsadhvika You're welcome for the help. In case you didn't notice, you made a couple of small mistakes in your first comment. The end result should be $f(x_1) \gt f(x) + f'(x_1)(x_1 - x)$. Thus, by multiplying both sides by $-1$, changing the $\gt$ to $\lt$ and rearranging the terms gives you the same inequality.

Comment: Yeahh I noticed after posting the comment. I fixed now.. Thanks again you're awesome:D

Comment: Hey John pardon to persist ;) I'm just cooking up few examples to convince more.. see any flaws in them?

Comment: 1) Driving a car: 

$f(x)$ represents a decelerating car. You're going forwards but your velocity is decreasing.  

Tangent line represents driving a car with `fixed` velocity. 

---If we start from the same place with same velocity, the Tangent line always stays ahead of $f(x)$

Comment: 2) Salary hike: 
$f(x)$ represents your hike. Every year you're getting a positive hike, but the hiked amount is `decreasing`.
  
Tangent line represents a `fixed hike` every year.  

---If we start the $f$ and  Tangent line from the same point with same hike, then clearly the $f$ always stays lower than the `fixed hike` Tangent line.

Comment: @rsadhvika If I understand what you wrote correctly, both of your real world type examples look like valid ways to visualize and demonstrate the inequality.